# Why do you create a unit vector by the sqrt of a vector

Tags: swift, math, vector, sprite-kit

I'm just following a great tutorial about Sprite Kit:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners

There's one thing I'm wondering about, the creation of a unit vector.
In this tutorial, the unit vector is created by calling the normalize function:

```
    func length() -> CGFloat {
      return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
  }

    func normalized() -> CGPoint {
        return self / length()
 }
```

This is later on used to make the "offset" vector to a unit vector:

```
let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position

let direction = offset.normalized()
```

I don't understand, why you calculate the length of the vector with a squrt and then divide the vector with the result. Couldn't you just divide the vector by itself to get to 1?

Comment: Because math? The equation with the square root is the distance between two points - in the case of a vector, one of the points is implicitly (0,0). A unit vector has a length of 1 by definition so it needs to be 'scaled' along such.

Comment: But doesn't the vector itself stand for a length?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Comment: How would you "divide the vector by itself", anyway? Vectors don't normally have multiplicative inverses defined.

Comment: @Gabkano The vector has a length/magnitude yes, *but not necessarily a length of 1* which is required to be a (normalized) unit vector.

Comment: If you take a vector with the length of e.g. 9 you can divide it by 9 to get to 1 or you can calculate the length by the squrt of x^2+y^2 ? or does the vector only stand for two coordinates?

Comment: @wim I understand how the squrt works, but not why you have to calculate the length again with it

Comment: but if you divide self / length, self has to be a length hasn't it? and if self already is a length can't you just say self / self

Comment: @Gabkano Oh, I see the confusion. First off, there is no *general* 'division' of vectors. Secondly, if we were to assume `x / x -> 1` (where x is some vector, allowed by some special rule) we end up with a constant 1; but the result desired is `vector / scalar -> normalized_vector` where the resulting type is still a vector, not a constant/scalar.

Comment: Now I understand, Thank You

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to divide a vector by a vector — such an operation is simply not defined, nor can it be meaningfully defined in general.

What you *can* do is divide (or multiply) a vector by a *number*, which simply divides (or multiplies) each element of the vector by that number.  In particular, multiplying or dividing every element of a vector by the same number will keep its direction unchanged (as long as the number is positive) and will multiply or divide its length by that number.

Thus, dividing a (non-zero) vector by its own length will leave its direction unchanged, but will change its length so that its new length equals its old length divided by its old length — that is, the new length of the vector will be 1, which (by definition) makes it a unit vector.

(The only case where this will not work is the all-zero vector, which has a length of 0.  It's not possible to convert the all-zero vector into a unit vector with the same direction, both because the result of dividing zero by zero is not defined, and also because the all-zero vector has no direction anyway.)